# property field is not shown in api call in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, postman

I am trying to add a property field to my serializer while creating Order objects creating the OrderItem objects at the same time. But it is not shown in the result while calling the post api.

There is no price filed in the result as shown here.

[image]

My models:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True
    #orderItem_ID = models.UUIDField(max_length=12, editable=False,default=str(uuid.uuid4()))
    orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12, editable=False, default=id_generator)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)



    #total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)

    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    order_item_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.varaints.price
        # return total_item_price
```

My serializers:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    price = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['id','order','orderItem_ID','item','order_variants', 'quantity','order_item_status','price']
        # depth = 1
```

Here I have put price in the serializer field, there is no error, but it doesnt show the price in the api in postman.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','user','ordered_date','order_status', 'ordered', 'order_items', 'total_price','billing_details']
        # depth = 1

    

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.is_seller:
            order_items = validated_data.pop('order_items')
            billing_details = validated_data.pop('billing_details')
            order = Order.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
            BillingDetails.objects.create(user=user,order=order,**billing_details)
            for order_items in order_items:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,**order_items)

            
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This is not a customer account.Please login as customer.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a field that have the same type as the return value for the property. In your case, I think IntegerField may work (I am not sure of the field type of your Product.variants.price).

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    # Use IntegerField instead of ReadOnlyField
    price = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['id','order','orderItem_ID','item','order_variants', 'quantity','order_item_status','price']
```